# Include Dependent JS files in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I figured out how to include a JS file in Node JS. But I have a JS file(hashing.js) which uses a function from other JS file(encoding.js).

In encoding.js, I have

```
exports = exports || {};
exports.encoding = encoding function
```

In hashing.js, I have

```
exports = exports || {};
exports.hashing = hashing function
```

The hashing function uses encoding inside it.

I am including them in Node JS like

```
var encoding = require (./encoding.js);
var hashing = require (./hashing.js);
```

But when I am including the JS files like this, running the hashing var throws an error

```
encoding is not defined
```

So I am unable to include JS files in Node JS which depend on some other JS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont do that

```
exports = exports || {};
exports.encoding = encoding function
```

do that

```
module.exports = function(){}
```

or

```
exports.encoding = function(){}
```

then

```
 var encoding = require (./encoding).encoding;
```

I suggest you take some time to read :

http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: The include part worked. But hashing is still not able to use encoding function.

Comment: Ok. I added the require encoding part in hashing.js and it worked like charm. Thanks.:)